# function with name as a data value of a div

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to execute a function which name is a data attribute value of a div:

```js
$('#dgok').click(function() {
    var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    window[fn]();
});

function delimg(){
    console.log('james'); // this works     
    let src = $('.imgact');
    let afn = 'store';
    $.post('images-pro.php', {afn, src}, function(data){  // line 75
        console.dir(data);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id='dgok' data-fn='delimg'>OK</div>
```

`TypeError: Illegal invocation...at delimg (images.js:75)`

Any help?

Comment: What's happen if we change `{afn, src}` to `{afn: afn, src: src}`?

Comment: @TânNguyễn, the same - `Illegal invocation...`

Comment: I believe that the problem is not with how the function `delimg` is being invoked, rather it seems to be related to the kind of data which is being posted. It seems as though `$('.imgact')` is not a valid piece of data to post, presumably because it's a dom element

Comment: Then, you can try again with `{afn: 1, src: 1}`. If it works, the problem comes from the way you get `afn` and `src`. If it is, try again with single property `{afn: afn}` and `{src: src}`. Then, you can know which makes the problem.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Without knowing exactly what `$('.imgact')` is, it's hard to know what it should be. I'm going to guess it's an input, though, so correct me if I'm wrong.

The issue is that you're trying to send data that jquery really doesn't want to let you send. `$('.imgact')` is an element, and if it's an input, we probably want its *value* rather than the element itself.

That would look like this:

```js
$('#dgok').click(function() {
    var fn = $(this).attr('data-fn');
    window[fn]();
});

function delimg(){
    console.log('james'); // this works     
    let src = $('.imgact').val();
    let afn = 'store';
    $.post('images-pro.php', {afn, src}, function(data){  // line 75
        console.dir(data);
    });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="text" class".imgact" />
<div id='dgok' data-fn='delimg'>OK</div>
```

Comment: you're right, thanks. The problem was with `$('.imgact'). What I need is `$('.imgact').attr('src')`.

Comment: `{afn, src}` is still invalid syntax. `{afn: afn, src: src}` should do it.

Comment: @maryisdead what do you mean by invalid syntax? It's valid in es6 https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Object_initializer#New_notations_in_ECMAScript_2015

Comment: @maryisdead it's really nice to use, just need to be careful with browser support, as it won't work in `ie`